# How to access the property of different concrete classes when interface is passed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am learning C# and trying to understand how to access different property of classes when interface being passed to the consumer class. Please guide me.

```
public interface ITest
{
    int ID {get; set;}
}

public class TestA: ITest
{
    public int A {get; set;}
}

public class TestB: ITest
{
    public int B {get; set;}
}


public void Test(ITest test)
{
    // how to check/access property of TestA 
    // how to check/access property of TestB
}
```

Attempt:

```
   public void Test(ITest test)
    {
        if(test.GetType() == typeof(TestA))
        {
             test.A = 45678;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `if (test is TestA tempTestA) { /* do stuff with tempTestA reference */ }`. Why are you doing this?

Comment: By passing an interface to the consuming class, you're declaring that the consumer is not interested in the specializations of this interface that might exist. There might be a valid reason for this, but to me, if you're sniffing a parameter's type, it is a big smell that your architecture is suboptimal and brittle. Explaining what you're *actually* trying to do here might lead to an answer that helps with this aspect.

Comment: You don't see to have implemented ID in either A or B.

Comment: I agree with spender that if you feel you have a need for this, your interface design is probably wrong.

Comment: By doing this you kill abstraction. If you need to have access to both properties just declare them inside an interface otherwise these properties shouldn't be visible because you're using an interface. But yes, to just check a type you can try several approaches that guys described below. But think, what if you need to add 3rd class with property C, you will also need to add a check to the consumer class. If your consumer needs these properties, just put them to the interface.

Comment: @spender -  Thank you so so much for this valuable feedback. One last question, so if I understand you correctly- Obviously anytime I add any standalone property to any concrete class I would have to do this casting and all. So you mean to say I should add all the properties always at interface level to avoid this type of casting?

Comment: @Unbreakable I wrote an answer to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's something implementation-specific that you need to do with inheritors of your interface, don't sniff type... write an implementation-specific method to do this for you. Now the caller doesn't need to know anything further about the interface:

```
void Main()
{
    var tests = new ITest[] { new TestA { A = 1, ID = 0 }, new TestB { B = 10, ID = 1 } };
    foreach (var test in tests)
    {
        test.DoSomeProcessing();
    }
}

public interface ITest
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    void DoSomeProcessing();
}

public class TestA : ITest
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public void DoSomeProcessing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A = " + this.A);
    }
}

public class TestB : ITest
{
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public void DoSomeProcessing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B = " + this.B);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could explicitly downcast it:

```
((TestA) test).A = 45678;
```

Comment: No check is required before?

Comment: @Unbreakable you already check `typeof` in your code - I just didn't bother repeating it.

Comment: Can you kindly tell me shall I follow your answer or the other one given by another user? Which one is more efficient?

Comment: @Unbreakable they both suggest the same thing

Answer (score 1):

You can use is keyword to check type and `cast` to TestA to assign variable

```
 public void Test(ITest test)
        {
            if(test is TestA)
            {
                 ((TestA)test).A = 45678;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your test cases don't implement `ITest`. It needs to be:

```
public class TestA: ITest
{
    public int A {get; set;}
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class TestB: ITest
{
    public int B {get; set;}
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can check the type via `is` and cast it or use [pattern matching](https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2017/02/15/patternmatching/) as following:

```
public void Test(ITest test)
{
    if (test is TestA testA)
    {
        var foo = testA.A;
    }

    if (test is TestB testB)
    {
        var foo = testB.B;
    }
}
```

Note, above is a C# 7.0 feature. When you can not use the new feature set, you need to cast them as following:

```
public void Test(ITest test)
{
    var testA = test as TestA;
    var testB = test as TestB;

    if (testA != null)
    {
        var foo = testA.A;
    }

    if (testB != null)
    {
        var foo = testB.B;
    }
}
```