# How to avoid casting derived types - Liskov's Principle violation

Tags: c#, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

I want to avoid using casting base class type to derived class type I can do this successfully If I want to access generic functionality but if I want specialised functionality I cant access this without casting

I have written code to demonstrate what I've already tried.

```cs
public abstract class Animal : IAnimal
{
    public void Move()
    {        
    }
}

public interface IAnimal
{
     void Move();
}

public interface IDog:IAnimal
{
    void bark();
}

public class Dog : IDog
{
    public void Move()
    {

    }

    public void bark()
    {

    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Animal animal = null;
    IDog dog = animal as IDog;

    dog.bark(); // can access specialized method

    IAnimal puppy = new Dog();
    puppy.Move(); // can only access generic functions    
}
```

How can I re-design classes to access "bark" method without casting?

Comment: You can't, it doesn't make sense that all animals can bark..because they can't. A whale can't bark so it can't have a bark method on the general class

Comment: What would you want to happen if the animal you were dealing with *wasn't* a dog? Note that I would recommend using an actual cast instead of `as` unless you're going to test whether the result is null. (i.e. if you expect that it's *always* going to be that type, use a cast.)

Comment: If you want to work with only `IDog` methods, then you shouldn't use `IAnimal`. The point of LSP is that you should be able to replace the object with a derived type and not care how it implements the methods. So `Dog` should really inherit from `Animal` and the method could be on the base class and called, say `Speak` for example. The dog class would output "bark" whereas the cat class might output "miaow".  OK, that's a poor example because not all animals can speak, but it should illustrate the point.

Comment: This question is like "I want to be full though I don't want to eat anything."

Comment: This question is effectively a dupe. I answered pretty much the same question a few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56690714 but there are variants of this question peppered all over SO over the years. Once I find the oldest, best candidate, I will return to cast my vote.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: You cannot and you shouldn't be able.

What you could do instead, is probably implement a `MakeNoise()` method in `IAnimal` interface because you'd expect animals in general to make noises.

However, if you insist on keeping `Bark()` on `IDog`, you wouldn't expect an `IDuck` to be able to access it - it should have a `Quack()` method. Neither will be available from objects downcasted to `IAnimal` because how can you guess whether it's a `Duck` or a `Dog`?

---

I'll post bit more "real life" example of why you might need inheritance in programming, because example you've provided is sort-of "book example" and thus it is obscure and vague as well.

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public static class DocumentHandling
    {
        public static List<IAccountable> Documents;
        public static dynamic InternalService { get; set; }
        public static dynamic IRS { get; set; }

        public static void HandleDocuments()
        {
            foreach (var document in Documents)
            {
                document.Account();
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IAccountable
    {
        void Account();
    }

    public abstract class Document
    {
        public int DatabaseId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

    }

    public abstract class DocumentWithPositions : Document
    {
        public int[] PositionsIds { get; set; }
    }

    public class Invoice : DocumentWithPositions, IAccountable
    {
        public void Account()
        {
            var positions = DocumentHandling.InternalService.PreparePositions(this.PositionsIds);
            DocumentHandling.IRS.RegisterInvoice(positions);
        }
    }

    public class Receipt : DocumentWithPositions, IAccountable
    {
        public void Account()
        {
            Invoice invoice = DocumentHandling.InternalService.ConvertToReceipt(this);
            invoice.Account();
        }
    }
}
```

See how I can stuff both `Invoice` and `Receipt` documents in single List (because they're downcasted to `IAccountable`)? Now I can account them all at once, even though their concrete implementations handle accounting process differently.

Comment: Pretty sure an earthworm doesn't make noises.

Comment: Yes but then IDog is rendered useless without casting animal. So I was wondering id there was a walk around without having to cast. and then what is the point of interfaces

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the idea behind downcasting. First of all, maybe explain in your post how your example violates Liskov's Substitution Principle. Also, why would you downcast a `Dog` to an `IAnimal` when you're just doing dog stuff? Downcasting gets useful when you're handling bunch of animals of different types at same time, such as `animals.ForEach(x => x.GoFindFood())` where `var animals = List<IAnimal>();`.

Comment: I've a bit more concrete explanation as to how you'd use inheritance instead of using unclear `IAnimal` book examples.

Comment: So imagine I had data coming in from IAnimal or Animal that is actually relevant to IDog or dog and I want to run the bark method on the IDog interface. I would have to create another IDog object to handle the bark method without being able to persist the IAnimal object passed through. I just dont see the use of having an IDog interface

Comment: Remember, we're still using silly book examples of `IAnimals` and `IRectangles` here. Real-life applications are easier to understand. But using your example, an `Animal` object will never be able to access `Bark` method, because while `Dog` and `Animal` share common `IAnimal` interface, an `Animal` class doesn't implement `IDog` interface. This is why you can't access more specialized methods from objects downcasted to more generic types.

Comment: However, I think you might be looking for this: `((Dog)puppy).bark()`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's takle the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) first and then talk about OOP and inheritance.

First, lets talk about [Abstract Data Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type). In her paper she uses the concept of objects from types.

An **Abstact Data Type (ADT)** is a description of a *type* with all it's *operations* and *behaviors*. All clients of an **ADT** should know what to expect when using it.

Here's an example:

Let's define a `Stack` as an ADT

***Operations:*** `push`, `pop`, `topElement`, `size`, `isEmpty`

***Behaviors:***

- `push` : ***always adds an element to the top of the stack!***
- `size` : return the number of elements in the stack
- `pop` : removes and element from the top of the stack. error if the stack is empty
- `topElement` : return the top element in the stack. error if the stack is empty
- `isEmpty` : return true is the stack is empty, false otherwise

At this point we desribed what is a `Stack` in terms of it's operations and how it should behave. We are not talking about clases here nor concrete implementations. This makes is an ***Abstract Data Type***.

Now lets make a type hierarchy. In C# both interfaces and classes are types. They are different as interfaces define only operations, so in a sense they are a contract. They define the operations of an ADT. Usually people do assume that only classes that inherit from one another define a type hierarchy. It's true that classes that inherit from one another are called *Superclass* or *Baseclass* and a *Subclass*, but from the point of view of *Types* we do have *Supertype* and *Subtype* for both interfaces and classes as they both define types.

*NOTE: For simplicity i'll skip error checking in the implementations of the methods*

```
// interfaces are types. they define a contract so we can say that
// they define the operations of an ADT
public interface IStack<T> {
    T Top();
    int Size();
    void Push(T element);
    void Pop();
    bool IsEmpty();
    }

// the correct term here for C# whould be 'implements interface' but from 
// point of view of ADTs and *Types* ListBasedStack is a *Subtype*
public class ListBasedStack<T> : IStack<T> {

    private List<T> mElements;

    public int Size() { return mElements.Count; }

    public T Top() { mElements(mElements.Count - 1); }

    public void Push(T element) { mElements.Add(element); }

    public void Pop() { mElements.Remove(mElements.Count - 1); }

    public bool IsEmpty() { return mElements.Count > 0; }
}

public class SetBasedStack<T> : IStack<T> {

    private Set<T> mElements;

    public int Size() { return mElements.Count; }

    public T Top() { mElements.Last(); }

    public void Push(T element) { mElements.Add(element); }

    public void Pop() { mElements.RemoveLast(); }

    public bool IsEmpty() { return mElements.Count > 0; }
}
```

Notice that we have two *Subtypes* of the same ***ADT***. Now lets consider a test case.

```
public class Tests { 

    public void TestListBasedStackPush() {
        EnsureUniqueElementsArePushesToAStack(new ListBasedStack<int>());
    }

    public void TestSetBasedStackPush() {
        EnsureUniqueElementsArePushesToAStack(new SetBasedStack<int>());
    }

    public void EnsureUniqueElementsArePushesToAStack(IStack<int> stack) {

          stack.Push(1);
          stack.Push(1);

          Assert.IsTrue(stack.Size() == 2);
   }
}
```

And the results are:

- `TestListBasedStackPush`: Pass
- `TestSetBasedStackPush`: FAIL!

`SetBasedStack` violates the rules for `push`: ***always adds an element to the top of the stack!*** as a set can contain only unique elements and the second `stack.Push(1)` wont add new element to the stack.

This is a violation of LSP.

Now about examples and type hierarchies like `IAnimal` and `Dog`. When you are in the ***right abstaction level*** a type should behave like it's suposed to. If you do need a `Dog`, use a `Dog`. If you do need an `IAnimal`, use `IAnimal`.

How do you access `Bark` if you have `IAnimal`? ***You DON'T!!***. You are at the wrong level of abstraction. If you do need a `Dog`, use a `Dog`. Cast if you have to.

```
public class Veterenerian {
    public void ClipDogNails(IAnimal animal) { } // NO!
    public void ClipDogNails(Dog dog) { } // YES!
}

private Veterenerian mOnDutyVeterenerian;
private List<IAnimal> mAnimals;

public ClipAllDogsNails() {
     // Yes
     foreach(var dog in mAnimals.OffType<Dog>()) {
         mOnDutyVeterenerian.ClipDogNails(dog);
     }
     // NO
     foreach(var animal in mAnimals) {
         mOnDutyVeterenerian.ClipDogNails(animal);
     }
}
```

Do you need to cast? Sometimes yes. If it better to not do it? Yes, most of the time.

How do you solve the above problem? You can make the Dog clip it's own nails. Are you doing to add method `ClipNails` to `IAnimal` and make only animals with nails implement this and leave other animal subclasses leave this method empty? NO! Because it doesn't make sense in the level of abstraction of `IAnimal` *and* it also violates LSP. Also if you do this you can call `animal.ClipNails()` and this will be fine, but if you do have a schedule that says that dogs should clip nails on Friday other animals Monday your stuck again as you can make all animals clip their nails, not only dogs.

Sometimes an object of one ***Type*** is to be used by objects from another ***Type***. Some operations doesn't make sense in a type. This example illustates how a Dog cannot clip it's nails. It should be done by a `Veterenerial`.

Yet we do need to work on the `IAnimal` level of abstraction. All things in a `Veterenerian Clinic` are animals. But sometimes some `operations` need to be performed on specific *type* of *animal*, a `Dog` in this case, so we do need to filter the ***animals*** by their ***Type***.

But that's a completely different problem from the above example with `Stack`.

Here's an example on when casting should not be used and the client code should not case about the concrete implementation:

```
public abstract class Serializer {
    public abstract byte[] Serialize(object o);
}

public class JSONSerializer : Serializer {
    public override byte[] Serialize(object o) { ... }
}

public class BinarySerializer : Serializer {
    public override byte[] Serialize(object o) { ... }
}

public void DoSomeSerialization(Serializer serializer, Event e) {
    EventStore.Store(serializer.Serialize(e));
}
```

`DoSomeSerialization` method ***should not*** care about the serializer that is passed to it. You can pass ***any*** `Serializer` that adheres to the `Serializer` spec, it should work. That's the point of having an abstraction with multiple implemenations. `DoSomeSerialization` works on the level of `Serializer`. We can define the `Serializer` as an ADT. All classes that are derive from `Serializer` should adhere to the specification of the ADT and the system works just fine. No casting here, no need to do casting here as the problem is different.